# How is repeating what Bnei Yisrael did somehow a "correction"?

Tags: midrash, sleep, shavuos, kabbalat-hatorah

According to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38951/2204) answer, it seems as though staying up late is somehow a correction for Bnei Yisrael sleeping late. I've heard it explained that they thought nevua would only come while they are asleep, and thus sleeping through that morning would allow them to receive the Torah.

Given all that: How is staying up late (and, consequently, sleeping a lot the next day) somehow correcting that mistake? If anything, it would cause us to repeat that mistake as many people end up sleeping most of Shavuot day due to it.

Comment: I think the sleeping bit was at daybreak. When Hashem showed up they were asleep.  We are awake when Hashem "shows up"

Comment: @YEZ And sleep through the rest of the meeting. But at least we said Hi!

Comment: I've heard some Rabbis say that if they had the ability they'd change the minhag to waking up early rather than staying up all night, but what can they do, the minhag is too entrenched for them to uproot.